# Rebase branch B on top of branch A and have the end result be the exact same content as branch B

Tags: git

I have:

```
O (origin/master) - - A (A)
                  \ 
                    - B (B)
```

`A` is a first version of the work done in `B`, but unfortunately `B` is not based on `A`, instead they are separate commits.

`A` will be merged into origin/master first creating:

```
O - - A (origin/master)
  \
    - B
```

`B` will be merged in a few days and I want the code on origin/master to be exactly the same as the code that is currently in the `B` commit.

With my own words: I want to append a new commit to `A` that removes all changes done in `A` and replaces them with the changes from `B`.

What is a simple way to do this using git?

Comment: I can't attempt an answer right now, because I also can't say that I follow your branching diagrams.  Can you edit your question and make the branch histories more clear?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I tried to make them clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear which final result you want, but this should help you on your way:

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD # revert the commit A
git checkout B
git rebase master # rebase B onto new master
```

now you'll have:

```
* previous history
* A, origin/master
* master (commit reverting commit A)
* B
```

I did not put any git push commands; I'll leave that to you. If you already want to include the work on B into master:

```
git checkout master
git rebase B
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a soft reset

```
git checkout --detach B
git reset --soft A # move to A revision, keep all differences between B and A in index
git commit -m "Setting up A to be just like B" # or whatever you want to write
git branch -f A
git checkout A
```

That should suffice

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout A
git read-tree -um @ B
git commit
```

The two-tree read-tree (`@` is a synonym for `HEAD`) is the core-command operation underlying checkout (also fast-forward merge), minus the `HEAD`-updating part.